# error: incompatible types java

Tags: java, arrays

I get this error message when i try to return result

```
error: incompatible types
char[][]result = ' ';   
                 ^
required: char[][]
found:    char
```

In this code.
I need to change the result into char [][] for another portion of 
my code but not sure how to do that. 
I just cant seem to get it.

```
public class Encryptor {

private int N;

public Encryptor( int N ) {
this.N = N;
}
////////////////////added/////////////////

public char[][] encrypt( char[][] P ) {
char ch;
char[][]result = ' ';   

for ( int i = 0; i < P.length; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < P[0].length; j++ ) {

ch = P[i][j];
    if ( ( ch >= '0' ) && ( ch <= '9' ) ) {
    ch = rotate( ch, '0', '9' );
    } else if ( ( ch >= 'A' ) && ( ch <= 'Z' ) ) {
    ch = rotate( ch, 'A', 'Z' );
    } else if ( ( ch >= 'a' ) && ( ch <= 'z' ) ) {
    ch = rotate( ch, 'a', 'z' );
    } else {
    // no need to encrypt
    }
result += ch;
}
}
return result;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////


private char rotate( char c, char min, char max ) {
int counter = N;

while( counter > 0 ) {
    c++;
    if ( c > max ) c = min;
    counter--;
}
return c;
}

public String encrypt( double D ) {
return encrypt( "" + D );
}

public int getN() {
return N;
}
}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you expect `char[][] result = ' ';` to do?

Comment: Are you coming from javascript?

Answer (score 3):

```
char[][] result = ' ';
```

`' '` is of *type* char, `result` is of type `char[][]` (array of `char` array).

As the compiler says, exactly, they are *incompatible types*.

You have two solutions:

- Weird solution: `char[][] result = {{' '}};`
- Not weird solution: `char result = ' ';`

Answer (score 0):

The `' '` value is a `char`, not a `char[][]`.
So you cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[][]result = ' ';
```

`' '` is single character so its incomitable to 2D array. 2D array initialize with `{{},{},..}`

```
char[][] result = {{' '}};
```

here result[0][0] would be `' '`.